# Run Python script as default program for .fits files in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I've written a script that takes a FITS file as input, displays an image, and does other fancy things, too. I'd like to essentially run (sorry, posting from mobile and don't see any code snippet buttons):

> python script.py --filename='the one I just double-clicked.fits' --input2=input2

This would happen as every .fits file is double-clicked.

Cursory googling has failed me, so any suggestions appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See the Windows `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` commands.

Comment: That'd work, thanks. Turns out the command prompt is disabled on this (work) PC. Unless there's another method, I may need an admin to type it for me, boo. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that is the default.  File association is set in the registry.  You need to be able to write to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and no matter what mechanism you use.